# Line Plus Bar Chart - Is there any way to pass date as string without formatting?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3 to display an Line Plus Bar Chart, but I'm getting some trouble to pass the date as string to the X axis.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm passing the string in the object like this:

```
"06-2013"
```

I want to display only month-year on the chart and I will apreciate if there's no need to format it.

Comment: You might be able to get around formatting the string as a date, but there really isn't any reason to! d3.time.format('%m-%Y') will take care of most of the hard work for you.

Comment: But in my application I don't want to convert my string `06-2013` to Unix Time... I want to pass it as is. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are not obligated to use something like `d3.format` or `d3.time.format`. You can return whatever value or type you like in the `tickFormat` function's handler.

If you have strings somewhere in your data that you want to use as label, just return them without formatting:

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return data[0].values[d][0]; // example, depends on data structure
});
```